# java.sql.SQLException Illegal operation on empty result set

Tags: java

Please help me: here is a sample of the code.
Everytime i press the login button it gives me java.sql.SQLExcpetion illegal operation on empty result set

Code for the Login Button:

```
 private void loginBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    con = DatabaseConnection.DBConnect();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE user_name = ? AND user_pass = ?";

    try
    {
        getPrivilege(username_Textfield.getText());

        prepStat = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        prepStat.setString(1, username_Textfield.getText());
        prepStat.setString(2,password_Textfield.getText());
        rs = prepStat.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {
            if (isAdmin == true)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Successful");
                mainDashboard mD = new mainDashboard();
                mD.setVisible(true);
                mD.setPrivilege(isAdmin);
                dispose();


            }else if(isAdmin == false)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login Successful");
                userDashboard uD= new userDashboard();
                uD.setVisible(true);
                uD.setPrivilege(isAdmin);
                dispose();
            }

        }else
        {


                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The username or password is incorrect","Access Denied", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                username_Textfield.setBackground(Color.red);
                password_Textfield.setBackground(Color.red);
        }





    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }


}
```

code for the connection class: 
the code here is for the DB connection i have a table called user which consists of user_id, user_name,user_pass, emp_id. all of which are set to not null

```
package guest_house;

//imports needed for the classs

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


 /**
 *
 * @author POWER
 */
public class DatabaseConnection {



public static Connection DBConnect()
{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement preStat = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/guest_house?","root","");
        return con;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
}



}
```

Comment: At which line is the exception happening?

Comment: It doesnt show me where the Exception is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column's name are `user_id`, `user_name`,`user_pass`, `emp_id` and table's name is `user`. But your sql sentence use `userName`, `userPass` and `users` words. You must change the sql sentence like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name =? AND user_pass=?"
```

Comment: sorry i edited the post now, i had copied the wrong code. please revise it again gimme feedback

Comment: What is your table's name? `user` or `user_table`?

Comment: Table name is user_table. This exception pops up only when I click the login button without any credentials

Comment: What is database's name? Is it `guest_house?` or `guest_house`